# Angularjs Bind Custom Attribute Once (like bindonce)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, custom-attribute

I like Bindonce a lot but I noticed it's attribute bindings are limited. I want to bind a custom attribute like `data-form="school._id"` and I want it only bound once. I know I can do something like `data-form="{{school._id}}'` but from my understanding that will create a watcher and I don't want that because I know it won't change.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$eval` in your link function: `scope.form = scope.$eval('form');`

This way `scope.form` is only set once.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying but this is not in a directive, it's in a ng-repeat